# Setting a variable with various conditional statements

Tags: python, syntax

I have this python coded statement:

```
is_headless = ["--headless"] if sys.argv[0].find('console.py') != -1 else [""]
```

1. In what way does the blank between `["--headless"]` and `if` control the code line?
2. How and would `"--headless"` ever be an element in the `is_headless` variable?
3. Using the variable name `is_headless` suggests the final value would
   be `True` or `False`. Is this correct thinking? In what case would `True` or `False` be assigned?
4. Is `[""]` a way to indicate `False`?
5. A little confused...

Comment: Could you clarify on the first point? -- In what way does the blank between ["--headless"] and if control the code line?

Comment: The blank has no effect, you can write `["--headless"]if` and it will have the same meaning. The blank just makes it more readable, like `foo = 1` instead of `foo=1`

Comment: Blanks are only necessary when there's no other delimiter to separate the tokens. You could write the whole line as `is_headless=["--headless"]if sys.argv[0].find('console.py')!=-1 else[""]`

Comment: ohhh, the space is what he meant. I was thinking it was that, but then I thought it couldn't be as simple. Though now I understand the ask a little better, however the last part "control the code line" is where I need to focus on now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. In what way does the blank between `["--headless"]` and `if` control the code line?

You can parse the statement as:

```
is_headless = <expression>
```

where `<expression>` is of the form `<true_value> if <condition> else <false_value>`. The expression evaluates to either `<true_value>` or `<false_value>` depending on the outcome of `<condition>`, and one of those two values is assigned to `is_headless`.

> 2. How would `--headless` ever be an element in the `is_headless` variable?

The overall effect is to assign one of two values to `is_headless`, either `["--headless"]` or `[""]`. Curiously, both of these are single-value lists. Let's talk about that...

> 3. Using the variable name `is_headless` suggests the final value would be `True` or `False`. Is this correct thinking? In what case would `True` or `False` be assigned?

That's exactly what I would expect based on the variable name. Which means it's a bad name. It's not being assigned boolean values so it shouldn't be named `is_xxx`.

> 4. Is `[""]` a way to indicate `False`?

It's supposed to indicate "no argument". As in, don't pass an extra argument to the following command. Having an empty string is probably a mistake; I would prefer to see an empty list `[]` instead of a list containing an empty string `[""]`.

It would be better if the variable were named simply `headless`, or `headless_argument`.

Or, what I would write:

```
extra_arguments = []
if sys.argv[0].find('console.py') != -1:
    extra_arguments.append('--headless')
```

That's how I would name it: `extra_arguments`. It's a list of extra arguments that may or may not be passed. By default it's an empty list, and if the condition is true then we add an extra argument `--headless` to the list.

> 5. A little confused...

I don't blame you!

Comment: A better name for the variable might be `headless_opt` because it holds the `--headless` option when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically that's a one-liner `if/else` statement in Python, which is pretty powerful and straightforward enough to use. I think the simplest way of understanding this, is to break the problem down so it's a little bit simpler and more digestible.

For example, substituting sample values such as 'a' and 'b' and using a string instead of arguments passed in the command line, should help make this more clear for illustration purposes:

```py
args = 'python console.py testing'
x = 'a' if args.find('console.py') != -1 else 'b'
print(x)

args = 'python testing'
x = 'a' if args.find('console.py') != -1 else 'b'
print(x)
```

Out:

```
a
b
```

---

*Also, for completeness, to circle back on your other questions:*

2. When the user's input contains the word `console.py`
3. Yes, the variable naming is not too great. A name of `is_headless` generally indicates the var is a boolean type, but here it is not the case, since the var actually is assigned a list of string, which could be annotated as a `list[str]` for example.
4. Well, technically `[""]` is not falsy, but an empty list `[]` could be considered falsy. I'm not too clear on why this is set here, perhaps added context might be helpful here however.